# when the actual jvm installation occured?

Tags: java, jvm

suppose I have a brand new os like windows 10.
I installed and run a software like intellij (written by java)
I didn't installed any jvm or jre, how can i run?

Comment: if not, does that mean, jvm installation occured in the middle of intellij installation??

Comment: [Duplicate] here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617865/how-to-run-java-program-without-jvm/25617961 and also see this: https://www.quora.com/Can-a-Java-program-run-without-JVM

Comment: IntelliJ ships with it's _own_ JRE. So when you run IntelliJ there's still a JVM. You can mimic this in your own applications using `jlink` / `jpackage` or some other similar third-party tool (note what IntelliJ does is more complicated since JetBrains maintains their own modified distribution based on OpenJDK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I run java software without jvm?

A "machine" can only run "machine code"(native binary). The machine code has to be compatible with the architecture of the machine you're running on.

A jvm is a program that emulates a machine virtually. You can think of a java `bytecode` as a special type of machine code that runs on java **virtual** machine. In other words, a `.class` file contains machine instructions that can run on a jvm.

So how does some software(Like IntelliJ) that has been written in java run on other machine architectures? That's because in those cases, they are not compiled to a bytecode that runs on jvm, Instead compiled directly to the machine instructions of the target platform.

The same `.java` code can be compiled to:

- `bytecode` to run on `jvm`
- windows native binary to run on windows environment
- `apk` to run on `Android`

and so forth

Comment: "_So how does some software(Like IntelliJ) that has been written in java run on other machine architectures? That's because in those cases, they are not compiled to a bytecode that runs on jvm, Instead compiled directly to the machine instructions of the target platform_" – As I mentioned in a comment to the question, IntelliJ does not pre-compile the bytecode to target specific machine code. Instead, it embeds the JVM/JRE with its installation. However, what you describe is definitely possible (e.g. GraalVM native image, though that uses the "Substrate VM").